# Make authenticated requests to YouTube from iOS always with same user

Tags: ios, authentication, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

Recently, YouTube decided to make video tags unavailable publicly. So to get the tags for a given video, I need to make an authenticated request to the API as the owner of the video. This is not a problem in my case as I'm fetching my own videos.

However, I'm confused about the authentication flow since YouTube strongly recommends to use OAuth2. Since I'm always going to authenticate as the same user (the owner of the video, aka myself), I definitely don't need to have any browser page for the actual user of the app to do anything. I see how I could have done it using ClientLogin (hardcoding login and password into the app) but I'm not sure how to approach this using OAuth2.

One last detail - that is not necessarily relevant since a high-level answer would be enough - is that I'm developing on iOS. Also I looked at this https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 and particularly the web server case which seems closest to mine but was not able to get a clear idea from it.

Thanks in advance for your help and don't hesitate if you need me to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OAuth flow that supports your use case.

In general, you should not be distributing your YouTube login as part of your application. Even if this were available via ClientLogin, after a certain number of logins, you would likely be presented with a challenge because the authentication servers would detect a strange usage pattern.

OAuth is not for distribution a single user's login to a large N, where N is the number of users of your application. OAuth is meant for your application to act on behalf of an end user, and because [tags are no longer exposed to end users through the UI](http://youtubecreator.blogspot.com/2012/08/tags-removed-from-video-watch-pages.html), it does not make sense to expose them to users via the API either. More details can be found here:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html

How many videos do you have? What is the purpose for needing the tag metadata? From a pragmatic perspective, here are a few alternative implementations that would be easier and would not require users to log in as you:

1. Store a single file mapping video IDs to tags on a server somewhere and fetch this periodically. [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) is a good place to do this.
2. Put the tag data in the description in a predictable format (you host the videos), and generate the metadata from this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Ikai, and thanks for offering alternatives. It's good to know that even using ClientLogin I might run into issues in the long run. Can you specify what you mean by "you host the videos" in the second alternative, because it seems that I could also use the description field from YouTube.